# adding node dynamically to treeview without using "SelectedNode"

Tags: c#, dynamic, treeview, treenode

I have a tree view that contains 3 roots and each root contains 3 children. I am wanting to add a node to one of the children. How do i do this using the node "name" instead of the user selecting a node (without the SelectedNode method).

For example:

- root1

  - a
  - b
  - c
- root2

  - d
  - e
  - f
- root3

  - g
  - h
  - i

The user will basically select which child to insert the node at by specifying the name of the node in a text box. After the user specifies inserting "foobar" into the node "g", the tree view would look like the following:

- root1

  - a
  - b
  - c
- root2

  - d
  - e
  - f
- root3

  - g

    - foobar
  - h
  - i

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

TreeView.Nodes["root3"].Nodes["g"].Nodes.Add(node);

Answer (score 0):

You can use `treeView.Nodes["key"]` when accessing and `treeView.Nodes.Add("key", node);` when building it.

Comment: i have tried using treeView.Nodes["key"] and it is not working.